# Searching for a pattern in a binary file using python script

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I want to find repeated copies of the config section within the partition dump (binary file), using pattern and 'magic' header. The config section always starts with 202 `'0xff'` bytes followed by 4 bytes `'\x00\x00\x23\x27'`. The script should identify different copies of configuration within the partition and print addresses (in bytes) where occurrences of the pattern starting. I adjusted an existing python script for my pattern, but it doesn't works, just throws errors, due to mixing bytes with strings.
How to fix this script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import mmap
import sys

magic = '\xff' * 202
pattern = magic + '\x00\x00\x23\x27'

fh = open(sys.argv[1], "r+b")
mf = mmap.mmap(fh.fileno(), 0)
mf.seek(0)
fh.seek(0)
for occurence in re.finditer(pattern, mf):
    print(occurence.start())
mf.close()
fh.close()
```

*errors:*

```
$ ./matcher.py dump.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eviecomp/BC2UTILS/dump_previous_profile/./matcher.py", line 13, in <module>
    for occurence in re.finditer(pattern, mf):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 248, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

pattern and magic:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal
As far as I can see, this has nothing to do with `grep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `re` can deal with byte strings (you just need to heed the warning message text and search for a `bytes` object, not a `str`), it seems overkill here.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mmap
from sys import argv

# NOTE: important to use `b''` literals!
magic = b'\xff' * 202
pattern = magic + b'\x00\x00\x23\x27'


with open(argv[1], "r+b") as fh:
  with mmap.mmap(fh.fileno(), 0) as mm:
    pos = -1
    while -1 != (pos := mm.find(pattern, pos + 1)):
      print(pos)
```

Or, for the beauty of modern Python, so you can also use an "iterator" over the matches:

```
from mmap import mmap
from typing import Generator
from sys import argv

def positions(mm: mmap, pattern: bytes) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
  pos = -1
  while -1 != (pos := mm.find(pattern, pos + 1)):
    yield pos

pattern = b'\xff' * 202 + b'\x00\x00\x23\x27'

with open(argv[1], "r+b") as lfile:
  with mmap(lfile.fileno(), 0) as mapping:
    all_positions = ", ".join(f"{pos:#0x}" for pos in positions(mapping, pattern))

print(all_positions)
```

Comment: the 1st variant gives `$ ./matcher.py dump.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eviecomp/BC2UTILS/dump_previous_profile/./matcher.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r+b") as fh:
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined`  and the 2nd variant: `$ ./matcher.py dump.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eviecomp/BC2UTILS/dump_previous_profile/./matcher.py", line 12, in <module>
    with open("largefile", "r+b") as lfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'largefile'`

Comment: Sorry! I was assuming your Python was fluent enough to replace strings by argv entries yourself as needed (and literally pointed out by the second error message). Fixed that.

Comment: The 1st variant works as expected - thank you! While the 2nd variant doesn't print anything, and no errors. There is probably, typo in pattern: `b'x2ff'`. It should be `b'xff'`, but this doesn't change anything.